# Why does tf.random.uniform generate duplicates inside a function but not in the main program?

Tags: python, numpy, function, tensorflow, return-value

I'm new to TensorFlow, and I was trying to understand how seed generation works (mainly with functions), my confusion is if I run this bit of code in my main program :

```
a = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
b = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
print(a)
print(b)
```

I get this output

**tf.Tensor([0.2390374], shape=(1,), dtype=float32) 

tf.Tensor([0.22267115], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)**

two different tensors (obviously) but if I try to call it from a function :

```
@tf.function
def foo():
  a = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
  b = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
  print(a)
  print(b)
  return a, b

foo()
```

I get this:

**Tensor("random_uniform/RandomUniform:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32) 

Tensor("random_uniform_1/RandomUniform:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32) 

(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.2390374], dtype=float32)>, 

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.2390374], dtype=float32)>)**

There's two things I don't get:

1. Why did the two prints inside the function show different output to the print from the return value of the function, in other words why was no value (numpy=array...) shown in the first two lines compared to the last two?
2. Why are `a` and `b` equal?

Comment: Thanks, I ran into exactly this issue, didn't know where to go for an answer, then my first web search brought me right here, and to bui's excellent answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's answer your first question

> Why did the two prints inside the function show different output to the print from the return value of the function, in other words why was no value (numpy=array...) shown in the first two lines compared to the last two?

## Eager Execution vs Graph Execution

At its core, Tensorflow works with *tensor operations* (ops). The expression `tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)`, for example, defines an op that, when executed, will generate a single random number with a seed of 1.

Now, you will need to actually execute this op to get a concrete random number. There are two ways to do that

1. **Execute this op right as soon as it is defined**. This is called Eager Execution (EE), and is arguably the most intuitive and flexible way to execute an op. It is also the default way to execute ops in TF 2.x
2. **Compose this op and possibly other ops together into a static, optimized computational graph and use that optimized graph for every execution**. This is called Graph Execution (GE). This was the default way to execute ops in TF 1.x, while in TF 2.x it is optional and can be enabled using the `@tf.function` decorator.

In EE context, the op `tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)` is executed as soon as it is defined and immediately returns a concrete value - an `EagerTensor` object.

```
a = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
print(type(a))
[Out]:
tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
```

While in GE, the op is simply a *symbolic reference* to a node in the optimized computational graph (a `Tensor` object to be exact). Whenever you invoke the function, the op is actually executed, at which time it produces a concrete value - an `EagerTensor`.

```
@tf.function
def genRandom():
    a = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
    print(f'a type is {type(a)}')
    return a

print(f'output type is {type(genRandom())}')
[Out]:
a type is <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
output type is <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

GE enables various static-graph optimizations to be performed to [improve execution performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function). EE, however, is far more intuitive and easier to debug as ops are executed on-the-fly instead of converted into cryptic graph nodes. A good practice is to debug functions in EE and wrap them in `@tf.function` in final production to leverage speed advantages of GE. Be careful though, as **some ops are allowed in EE context but not allowed or not available in GE context**.

## Graph Execution: Tracing

Going back to this example

```
@tf.function
def genRandom():
    a = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
    print(f'a is {a}')
    return a

_ = genRandom()
[Out]:
a is Tensor("random_uniform/RandomUniform:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

If in GE the op is only executed when the function is called, at which points it produces a concrete value, then why does Python `print` *inside the function* show a graph node ref instead of the concrete value that `a` produces?

This is because Python `print` is **not** a TF op, nor is it convertible to one. Therefore, it won't be included in the computational graph and won't be executed. However, you did get a printout when running the function so what's happening here?

Turns out that TF constructs graph lazily. That is, only when a function decorated with `@tf.function` is called for the first time does TF start constructing its graph. This is done by executing the function as normal Python code **once** to "record" the ops within the function - a process known as tracing - from which an optimized graph is constructed. After that, it is the constructed graph (and not the python code) who is called to produce the output.

In other words, Python's `print` - which is not an op - will work for the first call thanks to the tracing procedure. However, once tracing is done and the graph is constructed, it is not included in the execution graph and won't be executed for subsequent calls:

```
@tf.function
def genRandom():
    a = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
    print(f'a is {a}')  # not an op, will not be included in graph and only print during tracing
    return a

_ = genRandom()
[Out]:
a is Tensor("random_uniform/RandomUniform:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32)

_ = genRandom()
[Out]:
```

To get the actual value when the graph is executed, you'll need to use [`tf.print()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print) which is a valid TF op that'll be included in the graph.

```
@tf.function
def genRandom():
    a = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)
    tf.print("a is:", a)  # an op, will be included in graph and always print
    return a

_ = genRandom()
[Out]:
a is: [0.239037395]

_ = genRandom()
[Out]:
a is: [0.222671151]
```

As a side note, if you call an already-graphed function with arguments of types different than ones the function saw when it's last traced, [retracing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing) may happen (because the current graph may not be usable for this new type), in which case the python code inside the function is executed again. Retracing is very expensive and should be avoided.

---

For the second question

> Why are a and b equal in GE but not EE?

## tf.random seeds

Now you know what GE and EE is, go through this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed). It explains everything you wish to know about what the `seed` argument does and how ops internal *representation* differs in GE and EE mode. In short, the random number an `tf.random.uniform()` op creates completely depends on three factors

1. The global seed (which is set via `tf.random.set_seed`)
2. The op's own seed (which is passed to it constructor as the `seed` argument)
3. The op's internal counter, says `_count`, which counts the number of times the op has been executed. `_count` is reset to 0 everytime `tf.random.set_seed` is called

**In EE mode, identical ops share the same internal representation** and thus your `a` and `b` share the same `_count`. You get two different numbers because the value of `_count` involved in generating them actually differs by 1.

**In GE mode, each op has its own internal representation** and thus `a` and `b` have their own `_count`, which explains why you get the same number: everything involved in generating the two numbers are identical.

Comment: waw, what an answer, if this is not copied from somewhere, gg

Comment: Perfect! you explained everything, thank you so much. Do you know anywhere where I can find more detailed documentation about Graph Execution?

Comment: You can read more about GE [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs)

Comment: Thanks @bui this answer is **super** useful. Not only solving my problem with a one-liner of `@tf.function` but was a fantastic explainer for the complexity going on “under the hood” of TensorFlow.